# How to create boost::packaged_task with a functor?

Tags: c++, boost, functor

I'm trying to create a packaged task with a functor like this:

```
Worker w(someString, anotherString, i*length,length);
boost::packaged_task<Match> task(&w);
```

Operator in the Worker-class is looking like this:

```
Class Worker {
   Match operator()()
   {
      return matchText(..., ..., ..., ...);
   }
}
```

Compiler gives me error (translated the error-message from German)

> C2064: Statement results in no function which passes 0 arguments

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The constructor of boost::packaged_task [expects a functor object](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/doc/html/thread/synchronization.html#thread.synchronization.futures.reference.packaged_task) (either lvalue or rvalue), not a pointer to it.

```
boost::packaged_task<Match> task(w);
```

or

```
boost::packaged_task<Match> task(std::move(w));
```